# Possible to block traffic on port 443 by destination IP?

Tags: security, firewall

Is it possible to block traffic on port 443 based on the destination's ip address or is that encrypted?

Comment: Using what?  It's easy on IPTables, but NAT can put numerous PCs behind a single IP.

Comment: Yes you can. The traffic itself is encrypted but not the header details, because this shows where that information goes.  apache? cpanel? php? what system are you using

Answer (score 7):

Remember that networking works with layers: (simplified)

- IP
- TCP
- SSL
- data (HTTP for example)

The IP address is below the SSL layers, so it is not "encrypted". Your firewall can do filtering based on the source and destination IP and destination TCP port (443).